# Curl is getting POST response but node.js is not getting POST response

Tags: node.js, post, curl, response

When i use the following command i get correct JSON response:

```
$ curl --data "regno=<reg-number>&dob=<dob>&mobile=<mobile>"  https://vitacademics-rel.herokuapp.com/api/v2/vellore/login
```

When i use the following Node JS code i dont get response:

```
var request= require('request');
var querystring=require('querystring');

var credentials={regno: '13bit0036', dob:25051995, mobile:9431222422};
console.log(querystring.stringify(credentials));
request.post({
url: 'https://vitacademics-rel.herokuapp.com/api/v2/vellore/login',

headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
body:querystring.stringify(credentials),
}, function(error, response, body){
if(error) {
    console.log(error);
} else {
    console.log(response.statusCode + '\n' , body);
}
});
```

Comment: Have you looked at the actual request that's being sent?  I suspect it is not what you intend, since `json` is a boolean argument to `request`.

Comment: yes, i looked and i found that json is not the correct data type to send the data. so i modified the code. The current code is written above. The HTTP requestor addon (in forefox) gives correct response when content type is set to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". But the node.js output is still not correct,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add headers to your request as these:

```
headers: {
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0',
    'host': 'vitacademics-rel.herokuapp.com',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Connection':'keep-alive'
},
```

You will get response as required:

```
lalit@ubuntu-0:~$ node requesting.js 
regno=13bit0036&dob=25051995&mobile=9431222422
200
{"reg_no":"13BIT0036","dob":"25051995","mobile":"9431222422","campus":"vellore","status":{"message":"Successful execution","code":0}}
```

When you do curl it adds these headers by default.

Whenever you do a connection from a client or library `User-Agent`, `host`, `Connection` headers should always be added. Usually all websites require these headers.

To get the values for these headers, run URL in your browser and press F12, in Net read the request headers data send by browser. Enter same headers in your request.